# Can 挟带 be pronunced as jiādài?

Tags: pronunciation

In the song [千山萬水 at 1:13](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=-IWoful2Nqo#t=73s), the subtitles for the lyrics show 挟带, however, the word was pronunced as  jiādài instead of xiédài.

MDBG lists [夹带](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E5%A4%B9%E5%B8%A6)'s pronunciation as jiādài, and [挟带](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%8C%9F%E5%B8%A6)'s pronunciation as xiédài.

Can 挟带 be pronunced as jiādài? Or is the lyrics/pronunciation wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you can trust 周杰倫's pronunciation? :P

Comment: @CongXu after studying more, I found this question was in fact not easy at all.

Answer (score 6):

In ancient Chinese, [挟](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/631F.htm) can be used as 夹.

> 挟（挾）jiā ㄐㄧㄚˉ ◎ 古同“夹”，从物体两边钳住。

And in Taiwan, `挾` has a pronunciation jiá (note that it's **not** jiā). So, the lyrics/pronunciation cannot be considered wrong.

**PS** Thanks for NS.X.'s pointing out that ***you cannot freely choose the pronunciation of a polyphonic character, it should depend on the context***. That is correct, and I am sorry if I had misled anyone for my unclear statement.

That I said such pronunciation jiádài (Taiwanese) *cannot be considered wrong*, is because the persons who use jiádài may argue like this

> **(Possible Argument for jiádài)** The 挾 is an interchangeable character of 夾, though it's in ancient Chinese, I can use 挾帶 as 夾帶 without *being wrong* because modern dictionaries still list `挾jiá`(note that again in mainland China it is `挟jiā`) as one entry. And, 夾帶 has meaning `夾雜`(be mixed up with), so
>
> > the lyric `夢想夾帶眼淚` can be interpreted as a metaphor "dreams are mixed up with tears".
>
> And
>
> > in the news, `颱風夾帶暴雨前進` can be interpreted as "the typhoon mixed up with rainstorms is moving forward".
>
> They both make sense.

Thus, it would be a little indiscreet to say it's wrong.

## EDIT

Thanks for QuestionOverflow's brilliant question! I study the pronunciation of `挟带(挾帶)` for a while, and here's ***my conclusion***:

> 1. In Taiwan, the pronunciations of `挾` are **xié, xiá, or jiá**. The formal pronunciation of `挾帶` should be xiédài, or xiádài (preferred). However, the not-so-formal pronunciation jiádài can be commonly heard in TV weather reports.
> 2. In mainland China, the pronunciations of `挟` are **xié or jiā**. The formal pronunciation of `挟带` should be only xiédài.

### Literature Evidence

For Case 2, the answer can be easily found in the authoritative dictionaries 《现代汉语词典》 or 《新华字典》.

However, Case 1 is much more complex, because there are many dictionaries in Taiwan and it's difficult to tell which one is the most authoritative. Here, I would consider the `中華民國教育部 重編國語辭典修訂本` ([online](http://dict.revised2.moe.edu.tw/)) as the most authoritative one. In that dictionary, the entries for `挾` and `挾帶` are

- Pronunciation xié.

  > **挾** 部首　手　部首外筆畫　7　總筆畫　10
  >
  > > **注音一式① ㄒ｜ㄝˊ**
  > >
  > > **漢語拼音① xié**
  >
  > 【動】
  >
  > 1. 夾在腋下、懷夾。國語˙齊語：「時雨既至，挾其槍、刈、耨、鎛，以旦暮從事於田野。」孟子˙梁惠王上：「挾太山以超北海。」
  > 2. 從旁箝夾。文選˙王粲˙登樓賦：「挾清漳之通浦兮，倚曲沮之長洲。」
  > 3. 脅持。如：「要挾」。三國志˙卷三十五˙蜀書˙諸葛亮傳：「挾天子而令諸侯。」水滸傳˙第三十六回：「若是如此來挾我，只是逼宋江性命，我自不如死了。」
  > 4. 持握、持有。戰國策˙趙策四：「位尊而無功，奉厚而無勞，而挾重器多也。」楚辭˙屈原˙九歌˙國殤：「帶長劍兮挾秦弓，首身離兮心不懲。」
  > 5. 倚仗、倚持。如：「挾恃」。孟子˙萬章下：「不挾長，不挾貴。」清˙洪昇˙長生殿˙第三十齣：「況且弟兄姊妹挾勢弄權，罪惡滔天。」
  > 6. 夾帶、夾雜。宋˙辛棄疾˙浣溪沙˙梅子熟時到幾回詞：「晚雲挾雨喚歸來。」
  > 7. 懷藏、隱藏。如：「挾怨」。漢書˙卷五十六˙董仲舒傳：「秦繼其後，獨不能改，又益甚之，重禁文學，不得挾書。」元˙關漢卿˙望江亭˙第二折：「挾這讎氣，朦朧奏過聖人，要標取我的首級。」
- Pronunciation xiá. `①之又音` means it is another acceptable formal pronunciation under the usage of case ①.

  > **挾** 部首　手　部首外筆畫　7　總筆畫　10
  >
  > > **注音一式② （又音）ㄒ｜ㄚˊ**
  > >
  > > **漢語拼音② （又音）xiá**
  >
  > ①之又音。
- Pronunciation jiá.

  > **挾** 部首　手　部首外筆畫　7　總筆畫　10
  >
  > > **注音一式③ ㄐ｜ㄚˊ**
  > >
  > > **漢語拼音③ jiá**
  >
  > 【動】
  >
  > 1. 通達。詩經˙大雅˙大明：「天位殷適，使不挾四方。」
  > 2. 夾取。通「夾」。莊子˙駢拇：「問臧奚事，則挾策讀書。」舊五代史˙卷一二七˙周書˙盧文紀傳：「旭旦以箸挾之，首得文紀之名。」
  >
  > 【形】 周匝、周遍。荀子˙禮論：「於是其中焉方皇周挾，曲得其次序，是聖人也。」楊倞˙注：「浹，匝也。」
- **挾帶** `xié dài` with the meaning "carry".

  > 夾持攜帶。如：「歹徒挾帶毒品闖關，被海關緝查人員當場查獲。」
- **攜挾帶** `xī jiá dài` with the meaning "cheating in an examination".

  > 考試作弊。

Thus, consider the meaning of `挾帶` in the context of weather report, formally, it should be pronounced as `xiédài` or `xiádài`(preferred) in Taiwan.

### Why xiádài is preferred in Taiwan

I find an article written by Prof. Pei-Jung Huang (Dept. of Chinese language and literature, National Taiwan University) on [this website](http://www.chinesewaytogo.org/teachers_corner/expert/twoshore/twoshore.php). It mentions:

> 根據臺灣《國語一字多音審定表》（教育部出版）及大陸《普通話四讀詞審音表釋例》，兩岸的字音差異頗多，茲舉十例如下：[...]
>
> > 二、聲母、韻母或聲調不同的：（前面是臺灣讀音，後面是大陸讀音）[...]
> >
> > 21．挾持、挾制、挾帶（ㄒㄧㄚˊ／ㄒㄧㄝˊ）

That is to say, `xiádài` is preferred in Taiwan, according to the official document 臺灣《國語一字多音審定表》. And in the `國語小字典`, [挾](http://dict.mini.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/gdic/gsweb.cgi?ccd=3F9ps2&o=sjmpage&jmpage=1&ckmod=50&searchq=word%3D%22%E6%8C%BE%22) is only given the pronunciation xiá.

> 【挾】手-7-10
>
> 注音    ㄒ｜ㄚˊ
>
> (1)   用手臂夾在腋下。如：「挾帶」。
>   (2) 以威勢壓迫。如：「挾持」、「挾制」、「要挾」、「挾天子以令諸侯」。
>   (3) 暗藏於心。如：「挾怨」、「挾嫌」、「挾恨」、「挾隙」。

### Distinction between 挟带(挾帶) and 携带(攜帶)

- [挟带](http://www.zdic.net/c/f/7e/133081.htm)

  > 1. 携带；混杂在他物中秘密携带。 宋 梅尧臣 《和王仲仪咏瘿二十韵》：“挟带岁月深，冒犯风霜冷；厌恶虽自知，剖割且谁肯。” 清 富察敦崇 《燕京岁时记·黄花鱼》：“京师三月有黄花鱼，即石首鱼。初次到京时，由 崇文门 监督照例呈进，否则为私货。虽有挟带而来者，不敢卖也。”
  > 2. 谓以强力带着。 王愿坚 《普通劳动者》：“一阵疾风挟带着沙土扑过，大白点子雨急骤地撒落下来，打在沙土上。”
  > 3. 犹夹杂，带有。 鲁迅 《坟·从胡须说到牙齿》：“其中大半是因为他们耽误了我的父亲的病的缘故罢，但怕也很挟带些切肤之痛的自己的私怨。”
- [携带](http://www.zdic.net/c/a/8b/151635.htm)

  > 1. [carry;bring;take along]
  > 2. 随身带着
  >
  >    > 携带行李
  > 3. 经受或容许以特定方式带
  >
  >    > 易于携带的负载
  > 4. [pack]∶作为部分经常装备佩带
  > 5. [wear]∶手里拿着
  >
  >    > 携带一根手杖

Thus, though they have similar meanings, `携带` can be only used to describe such an action or a status of humans, or, of something that is compared to humans in a metaphor. `挟带` emphasizes more about the action than the status, and can be used for anything/anybody. The phrase `挟带暴雨` is Case 2 of `挟带` in the explanations above, meaning "carrying (the rainstorm) with strong force".

### Video Material Evidence for the Formal Pronunciation xiádài in Taiwan

1. [One official introductory video about typhoon](http://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7/media/video/edu_video6.htm) made by the **Central Weather Bureau of Taiwan**. 挾帶 is pronounced as xiádài at 0:05-0:06.

   > 颱風是源自於熱帶海洋上的劇烈天氣系統，會挾帶(xiádài)著狂風及豪雨前進 ...
2. [A piece of weather news](http://ap.ntdtv.com/b5/20130518/video/109427.html) made by New Tang Dynasty Asia Pacific TV. 挾帶 is pronounced as xiádài at around 0:05.
3. [A piece of Apple Daily news in Taiwan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwwdAZKLpW8). 挾(帶) is pronounced as xiá at 0:00.

   > 挾1500毫米暴雨 ...

### The Not-So-Formal Examples of jiádài

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONcmt4TIalc

   > Around 0:05. 明天起將挾帶暴雨侵台
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iREbExawzeQ

   > 0:08-0:12 其中，西半部依然挾帶豐沛水汽進入台灣
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03_2kam1MrY

   > 0:24-0:28 天秤颱風從東部登陸台灣，挾帶著強風豪雨

Comment: I agree with you. I just want to add that the word 挟带 is almost always chosen over 携(xié)带 when used to described the natural elements such as the rain, e.g. [挟带暴雨](http://news.xinhuanet.com/photo/2009-08/10/content_11854265.htm). Taiwanese news reporters always pronounced it as jiādài, perhaps to differentiate the two? I am not sure how Chinese reporters pronounce this though.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow nice question!!! See my edit. Briefly speaking, formally, 挟带(暴雨) in Taiwan should be pronounced as `xiádài`. And, though the weather news in mainland not often use 挟带 and I cannot find an online video, I am sure the formal pronunciation in mainland should be `xiédài`, as authoritative dictionaries show that.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow and for the distinction of 挟带 and 携带, you are right, 携带 can only be used to describe an action or a status of a human.

Comment: +1 for the research. The edit is awesome but I would argue with the original statement (the character has pronunciation X so it is not wrong to pronounce so). 多音字的发音需要逐词分析，不能一概而论。

Comment: @NS.X. Your logic is correct. I will edit my answer. I didn't state it clearly enough (ah, my English is not so good). What I want to state, is, the character has a pronunciation X ***and in that case the meaning makes sense***. As 挟 is an interchangeable character of 夹, and 夹带 has meaning "carry secretly/be mixed up with", so the jiádài-style people also would argue that 台风夹带暴雨 means "typhoon is mixed up with rainstorm". It makes sense, though in another meaning.

Comment: Thanks for digging out the third pronunciation `xiá`. I could have mistook it for `jiá` as it wasn't found in most dictionaries. Nice answer :)

Comment: @Stan Thanks for the persistent update, the answer looks perfect now:)

Comment: I think the dictionaries in Mainland China already deleted the "jiā" pronunciation now. I cannot find this pronunciation in my 《现代汉语词典》（第7版）(published in 2016). There is only the pronunciation "xié". "Jiā" is wrong now.

Comment: And I agree you with your opinion of its ancient pronunciation. I found it in 《古汉语常用字字典》(The Commercial Press, 2015, Beijing). It also meant "周全" in Ancient Chinese, the same as "浃".